# Trying to Display init value in form

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to display the init  value (State) in my form, but it keep showing the "-------" value. 
I know the value is not empty because it saves the states into my database. It just wont show up in my form

[image]

My form class:

```
class AddressUpdateForm(BaseModelForm):
state = ProvinceModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=CountryProvincePair.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Address
    fields = ('label', 'postal', 'zip', 'city', 'country', 'state', 'custombillto')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AddressUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print("THIS IS IT", self.instance.state)
    self.fields['state'].instance = self.instance.state
```

My custom ModelChoiceField:

```
class ProvinceModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
"""
A model choice field that accepts custom values for province class.
Should be used together with Chosen with extended functionality.
This model will accept everything that is not in its Query initial values
"""

def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return "%s, %s" % (obj.province, obj.country)

def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    try:
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
    except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
        # If the object does not exist, does not raise an error
        pass
    return value
```

BaseModelForm:

```
class BaseModelForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for label, field_instance in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field_instance, ModelChoiceField) or isinstance(field_instance, ChoiceField):
            field_instance.widget.attrs['class'] = 'chosen'
            field_instance.help_text = ''
        if isinstance(field_instance, BaseTemporalField):
            field_instance.widget.attrs['class'] = 'dp'
        if isinstance(field_instance, NullBooleanField):
            field_instance.widget.attrs['class'] = 'switch'
        if isinstance(field_instance, BooleanField):
            field_instance.widget.attrs['class'] = 'switch'
```

Comment: Any reason for using `BaseModelForm` instead of `ModelForm`? `Modelform` inherits from `ModelFormMetaclass` as well as `BaseModelForm`. There is some field update logic in `ModelFormMetaclass` which your form is missing.

Comment: BaseModelForm is the same as ModelForm, i have added it to the question.